# How to render DIV element with a button click on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I was working on a form , and I want to render same div in "Active Membership" Section when  add more button is pressed. User can have several Active membership, so each time user pressed the button same input section will render. I guess for loop can help but it is not working inside jsx codebase. I am using formik for creating the form.
[image]

Comment: Since you are using Formik, you should consider using https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray for this case .

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement that using `<FieldArray />`.

> <FieldArray /> is a component that helps with **common array/list manipulations**. You pass it a name property with the path to the key within values that holds the relevant array.

Resource - Official Documentation (https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray)

```js
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Friend List</h1>
      <Formik initialValues={{ memberships: [] }}> {/* Initialize a membership empty array*/}
        {(props) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray name="memberships">
              {({ push, form: { values } }) => (
                <div>
                  {values.memberships &&
                    values.memberships.length > 0 &&
                    values.memberships.map((item, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <Field
                          name={`memberships.${index}.name`}
                          placeholder="Membership Title"
                        />
                        <Field
                          name={`memberships.${index}.position`}
                          placeholder="Position"
                        />
                        <Field
                          name={`memberships.${index}.join.date`}
                          placeholder="Join Date"
                        />
                      </div> {/* Active Membership section */}
                    ))}
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => push({})}> {/* Create the click handler */}
                    Add More
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </FieldArray>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-add-more-ncsw3?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if you need further support.